# What Metadata does Cloud Speech to Text collect

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I understand data logging for Cloud Speech to Text is disabled by default.

Does Google Cloud really not log calls while they are being processed? What exactly is logged? What happens to the logs after calls are processed?

Please advise, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/data-logging). Google owns the models developed from your data. The logged details are not provided to customers.

> By default, Speech-to-Text does not log customer audio data or
> transcripts. To help Speech-to-Text to better suit your needs, you can
> opt into the data logging program. The data logging program allows
> Google to improve the quality of Speech-to-Text through using customer
> data to refine its speech recognition service. As a benefit for opting
> in, you gain access to discounted pricing.
>
> When you opt into the program, Google does not log all of your data:
> Google only uses the data sent to Speech-to-Text on the project with
> data logging enabled. You can continue to use other Google Cloud
> projects without data logging enabled. Google only uses the data that
> you send to those projects as needed to provide the service.
>
> You continue to maintain full ownership of all data that you upload to
> a project with data logging enabled. However, Google retains ownership
> of the actual models trained from that data. For more details about
> the terms and conditions for data logging, see the terms for [opt-in
> for data
> logging](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/data-logging-terms).

No logging details are provided to you. The logged details are based solely on the data you submit (speech files) to Google.

Comment: Thanks! My initial concern was that things like IP addresses when I sent the recording to Google Cloud would be logged. Anyway, since I'm sending it from my servers, my customers identity would be protected. Thanks!